# Outlook Mail Search Api

Tags: api, email, search, outlook

I will be working on the outlook mail search api and as i have read in the documentation

Outlook Rest Mail API Documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#get-messages

Simply querying using $search parameter:

```
url: https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/MailFolders/INBOX/messages?$select=Sender,Subject,From,CcRecipients,HasAttachments,Id,SentDateTime,ToRecipients,BccRecipients&$top=10&$skip=0&$search=sample email
```

With search criteria "from:" Keyword:

```
url: https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/MailFolders/INBOX/messages?$select=Sender,Subject,From,CcRecipients,HasAttachments,Id,SentDateTime,ToRecipients,BccRecipients&$top=10&$skip=0&$search=from:invitation
```

They have **$search** keyword but by using $search i am getting **BAD REQUEST**. According to my understanding $search is not supported by Outlook API.

Anyone has any idea how i can perform the search over the mails as i want to perform folder wise search operation?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

G-reetings.

How about using double quotes to wrap your `subject` search?

Like this one

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/MailFolders/INBOX/messages?$select=Sender,Subject,From,CcRecipients,HasAttachments,Id,SentDateTime,ToRecipients,BccRecipients&$top=10&$skip=0&$search="from:invitation"
```

Or use urlencode all along

```
%22from%3Ainvitation%22
```